# Amazon EC2 link to Bigrock domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a simple question for **pointing** **my Bigrock Domain name to Amazone EC2.**

I have **Created HostedZone** from [Hostedzone-create link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/)
I **got 4 name servers.**
Now what?
Suppose my domain name is example.com on Bigrock.com.
Can anyone explain me how can i point that domain name to EC2?
I **asked to Bigrock support** but they told me something like this:

> The website is not working because the DNS zone for your domain is not
>   configured properly on your Hosting providers DNS servers ( AWS Server
>   ). Please get in touch with your provider for further assistance.

But I am **not getting** what they want to say. Please help!!

Comment: You moved your hosted zone from Bigrock to AWS Route 53 right, so you have to apply the changes to point example.com to EC2 in  AWS Route 53 what is your domain?

Comment: this is my domain: http://www.wolgonandthesevenworlds.com/

Comment: created hosted zone and got some name servers. what to do now?

Comment: Ok follow steps in this to change the name servers in bigrock once you change them give it like 24 - 48 hrs for change to take effect http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/how-to-change-name-servers-with-bigrock

Comment: There is a video too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwSZiq1JK2o

Comment: why downvoted? I am not aware about this. and sure so many users will find answers if they have domain name from Bigrock.com.

Comment: It was not me who down voted.

Comment: @error2007s hmm.. but I am sure that this will be userful for others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118099/discussion-between-error2007s-and-pathik-vejani).

Comment: Down voted because it's not a programming question so it doesn't belong on this site. It is just a DNS configuration question that you could have easily looked up the answer to. Note: You could have just modified/added a few DNS records to your old DNS configuration instead of going through all the trouble (and added expense) of moving everything to Route53.

Comment: This may help [Register GoDaddy Domain with AWS ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366982/register-godaddy-domain-with-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move your Name Servers to AWS Route 53 first you have to change the Name Servers in Bigrock follow this steps.

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/how-to-change-name-servers-with-bigrock

Once that is done go to AWS Route 53 and create two record sets one for the "naked domain" and another for "www" domain and add a A-Record to point to the EC2 IP address (Be Sure the IP address is Elastic just in case for future change in IP address of the server so that you are covered).

This is Route 53 Guide

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html

Comment: Thank you for saving my time and guide me

Comment: Do we need any other record set in AWS Route 53?

Answer (score 2):

Now, you will go to your bigrock.com and find your domain. Change the default name servers information with that 4 name servers information provided by Route53 on amazon. save your changes and wait for few hours to be activated properly.

Comment: but those 4 name servers have .co.uk, .org, .net etc.. what is that?

Comment: can you please post this as comment?

Comment: You will give all 4 name servers information in your bigrock account like bellow:
1. name server one:  ns-1903.awsdns-45.co.uk
2 . name server two : ns-1162.awsdns-17.org
3. name server three: ns-558.awsdns-05.net
4 name server four : ns-260.awsdns-32.com
I hope your understand the things

Comment: what is inside below?

Comment: yes i got but there are 2 record set count in Amazone route like below http://prnt.sc/bwlcvc

Comment: I copies all 4 name servers, but now what?

Comment: You just cope the NS info